# Minecraft: PC with Windows 10 Upgrade?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

I have Minecraft PC on my computer, which is on Windows 7. We are upgrading to Windows 10. 
My question is, can I play my current version on Windows 10, or must I play the Windows 10 Pocket Edition Style gameplay? If I must have the Windows 10 edition, do I have to buy it, or will it be free since I bought regular Minecraft?

Comment: Related: [Can you get Minecraft Java for free if you have purchased Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/389361/4797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two versions of Minecraft that Windows 10 can run - the standard desktop version, and the Windows 10 Beta version. You can download both on [minecraft.net's download page](https://www.minecraft.net/en/download/).

The standard desktop version is the one you'd want to install, and runs exactly the same between Windows 7 and Windows 10. The Windows 10 Beta features cross-platform play with Pocket Edition, and you can get a free download code from your Mojang account.

Comment: You don't know how relieved I am to here that :)

Comment: @DanielG Yeah, I thought the same thing while I was upgrading 0.0

Comment: Windows 10 is no longer beta btw

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Yes, you can play the normal Windows version if you're on Windows 10.

If you have Minecraft Java Edition (pre-Windows 10) already, you also have access to Windows Bedrock Edition (Windows 10 Edition) for free (as of June 7, 2022 — [the two are sold together now](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/java---bedrock-edition-pc-out-june-7)). Both editions will show up in the Minecraft Launcher.